# How to use motioncontroller thumbstick move (not press) to teleport motion controller pawn in UE4

Tags: oculus

To clarify the title: I'm using the built in VR blueprint, Oculus Touch controllers as my MotionControllers, and I'm trying to replicate the teleport style that RoboRecall uses (which should be possible given that RoboRecall was made in UE4 by EPIC themselves).

The blueprint does have a teleport feature built in, but it's activated by pressing 
the thumbsticks in (as in pressing the thumbstick down until you hear the button click), what I'm hoping to do is instead activate it on thumbstick push (as in just tilting and move the thumbstick around, but not clicking it down).

So I can actually get it half working by just changing the input in the `game settings > inputs` section, but when you release the stick it loses the rotation data (though it does actually move your charecter to the right xyz).

So it would seem that the first part (activating the teleport blueprint stuff) activates when the thumbstick is moved, it requires the thumbstick to fully return to centre in order to move the player, which by then has lost rotation. 
I'm new it UE4 and it might be a simple fix, so any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to do the same, I want a teleportation system that works like Robo Recall. Better yet, like the Oculus Home, which is almost identical, but Oculus Home is faster to open up when trying to figure out how it works, and I believe has some more functionality than Robo Recall.

I didn't go much farther than you on developing this system, but perhaps we can help each other; do you have a 360 or 180 degrees setup?

The way the teleport on Robo Recall and Oculus Home works is like this: it has a deadzone on thumbstick push for activating the gizmo, and a smaller deadzone on releasing the stick for the actual execution of the teleport. This way it allows you to teleport before the stick re-centers, keeping it's direction. The bigger deadzone on pushing the stick for showing the gizmo is also important so you don't teleport right away when pushing it.

So the gizmo display action shouldn't run right after the stick input action, but after the stick axis value is bigger than the deadzone1 and the teleport action shouldn't run on input release, it should be also on the action, but happen when the axis value is smaller than the deadzone2.

I managed to make it work. I used my gamepad stick and a print string just to debug, should work with the motion controllers too. Check this out:

[image]

Comment: can someone please demonstrate how this fits with the rest of the teleport blueprint.
Thanks